# How to print out the nth most frequent words in a binary search tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This concerns "a software algorithm" https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

I am currently writing a word counter dictionary program. To store the different word counts, I am using a Binary Search Three with the word as the key and the frequency as the value.

Here is my Binary Search Tree class

```
public class BinarySearchTree<AnyKey extends Comparable<? super AnyKey>, AnyValue>
    implements MyTreeMap<AnyKey, AnyValue>{
              protected BinaryNode<AnyKey, AnyValue> root;
              protected BinaryNode<AnyKey, AnyValue> insert(AnyKey x, 
                      AnyValue y, BinaryNode<AnyKey, AnyValue> t ){
                    if( t == null )
                         t = new BinaryNode<AnyKey, AnyValue>(x, y );
                   else if( x.compareTo( t.element ) < 0 )
                         t.left = insert( x, y, t.left );
                  else if( x.compareTo( t.element ) > 0 )
                        t.right = insert( x, y, t.right );
                 else
                          throw new IllegalArgumentException( x.toString( ) );  
                return t;
      }
```

And here's my node class

```
class BinaryNode<AnyKey, AnyValue> {
      BinaryNode( AnyKey theElement, AnyValue theValue ){
          element = theElement;
          value = theValue;
          left = right = null;
       }
       AnyKey             element; 
       AnyValue    value;
        BinaryNode<AnyKey, AnyValue> left;    
       BinaryNode<AnyKey, AnyValue> right;  
     }
```

I am trying to write this method inside my Binary Search Tree

```
@Override
public void PrintMostFrequent(int n) {

}
```

Where it will print out the nth most frequent words based on frequency. I have an idea for how to do this  in psuedo code.

1. Create a collection to hold nodes

2. Add all the nodes from the tree to this collection

3. Sort the collection based on counts

4. Iterate sorted collection and print out the nth most frequent.

Is this the best way to solve this problem/write this method? I was afraid that creating a separate collection might be spaciously too expensive and the sorting would be computationally expensive as well.

Comment: Have you considered using a TreeMap for your main tree?

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard Yeah but trying to implement my own data structure, not use a java built in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be:

1. Initialize a `TreeSet<Node> result` sorted by node word frequency.
2. Add the first n elements from your tree to the set.
3. Iterate through the rest of the elements, replacing the lowest value in the set with higher values. `if current > result.lowest() then result.pollFirst(); result.add(current)`

This has limited spacial cost and should be faster, as most elements can be skipped directly.

Note however, that unless you are dealing with huge arrays and have traced slowdowns to this function, your solution's simplicity makes it the better choice.

Comment: How would determine the first n elements of your tree?

Comment: @committedandroider I meant the first n elements when iterating through the binary search tree. It doesn't matter which ones they are -- the point is to fill up the set.

Comment: sorted set as in tree set?

Comment: would you have to have a compare to in the node class to support this(comparing of elements)?

Comment: @committedandroider A TreeSet works, yes. You do no necessarily need a compareTo() method, you can implementent a Comparator and pass it to TreeSet's constructor.

Comment: You would still have to have a compareTo method  - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Comment: theres no pollFirst in SortedSet - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Comment: @committedandroider You need a compare method somewhere, either as `compareTo` when implementing `Comparable`, or as `compare` when implementing `Comparator`. The `Comparator` can be a separate class, however. TreeSet has a pollFirst.

Comment: I just did Collections.sort with a Comparator

Answer (score 0):

Your Method describe is also pretty much good . It will be complex when you consider need to added one insert new word into the there one fro inserting into the tree which will take O(logn) and on the sorted list O(n) in worstcase Then for searching again O(n).

For better performance over searching  of for nth frequent node and inserting one method would be create **one more BST** but with frequency .  So for inserting a new node in both tree will take O(logn) and for searching O(logn) .

In the above method you have redundancy for data i.e 2nd tree will have word and frequency both . So for avoiding that what you can do is in 2nd BST just put frequency and one reference  to node of the word in the 1st BST with this you can jump from one tree to another tree any point of time.

Comment: I am only planning on calling this after everything has been inserted, so you can see all the word counts. Will it still be complex?

Comment: BST is useful if the searching element is "Key"  not its values. In Your case the search element is "Value". So , here BST is of no use when "Value" is considered . So either you create another BST with values as key or your approach is also good i.e sorting the node by its Values

Comment: If I were to go with the one more BST approach, where would i keep that tree?